# Does one need jQuery when using Twitter Bootstrap with Angular.js?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

Is the jQLite (in built with AngularJS) sufficient to execute javascript functionality (like dropdowns) in Twitter Bootstrap?

[docs.angularjs](http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq) says:

> DOM Manipulation from  Stop trying to use jQuery to modify the DOM in
>   controllers. Really. That includes adding elements, removing elements,
>   retrieving their contents, showing and hiding them. Use built-in
>   directives, or write your own where necessary, to do your DOM
>   manipulation. See below about duplicating functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Angular UI Github](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap), no.

```
Native AngularJS (Angular) directives for Twitter's Bootstrap. Small footprint (5kB gzipped!), no 3rd party JS dependencies (jQuery, bootstrap JS) required! 
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
```

Though bear in mind this is a wrapper made specifically for Angular UI, you may/may not be able to easily use bootstrap plugins others have written with this.

However with a default Angular UI & copy of bootstrap then you'll need jQuery as the code in the github repository has been heavily modified to work without jQuery.

[Edit] As noted in the comments [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) is a very good option as well.

Comment: any drawback of using Angular UI Bootstrap? I was using bootstrap and angular separately. Is making a switch advisable from the reliability perspective?

Comment: Reliability you'll be fine, you will be mostly dependant on them for updates though e.g 3.0 - though it seems a popular project so it'll probably be a quick release schedule.

Comment: yes. i'm not using bootstrap 3.0 for my own reasons. Thanks for the heads up. Appreciate it!

Comment: this doesn't answer the original question. twitter bootstrap does depend on JQuery. ui.bootstrap doesn't have everything that is there in twitter bootstrap.

Comment: @Nishith it has a good quantity of the feature set of bootstrap, as I specify it's not a complete replacement but it is bootstrap for angular UI.

Comment: [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) has become quite mature, and this is the best way to implement bootstrap with angular

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Angular UI bootstrap then jquery is not required

[Try this sample site](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)